# What do you think is the best way to learn English properly?

Tags: difference

I has studied with a grammar book and read and listened many contents in internet (ex: Youtube, news in English ) since I started English.

I know there is no shortcut in learning language.

But I want to know some tips to study more effectively.

And I just got to know there were many ELL who study with wrong way.

- For example :

.. Some students study with only exam papers.

.. Some students only repeat speaking with Movies or series in English ( even though they know only 
alphabet )

so .. What do you think about it ?

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

All a matter of preference. I would say mostly dedication first of all, seems like you are quite dedicated if you have gotten this far.

I would suggest watching as many things possible in English so that you can understand and remember the proper sentence structures.

I have been learning Spanish and what has helped me is to use it constantly and be immersed.

The best way people say to learn a language is to be fully immersed in it, whether it be news, tv, youtube, your search bar, talking with native English speakers. That is one of the fastest ways to becoming fluent.

Overall, keep it up, you are doing well so far.